# Can you use datalist with HTML textarea?

Tags: html, forms, textarea, html-datalist

I wanted to check if it's possible to use datalist with a textarea. I have it working with an input field, but the task I have here requires me to *"add input suggestions to a one row textbox with datalist"*. Does that even make any sense?

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        Välj favoritbild med hjälp av datalist - skriv i listan nedan
    </legend>
    <input list="bilar" name="bil">
    <!--<TEXTAREA list="bilar" NAME="bil" ROWS="1"></TEXTAREA>  -->
    <datalist id="bilar">
        <option value="Dodge Viper">
        <option value="Honda Civic">
        <option value="Corvette Z06">
        <option value="Volvo V70">
        <option value="Ferrari Spider 360">
    </datalist>                 
</fieldset>
```

However, I can't get it working with my textarea (which is commented out above). It works with the input-element however.

Anyone know how I can get the above example working with a one-row textbox?

Comment: An `input` of `type=text` **is** "a one row textbox". Textareas are for multiline textboxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because [`datalist`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element) by definition associates with an `input` element. Moreover, selecting an item drom a `datalist` means replacing the entire value of the associated `input` element, instead of appending to it, which normally be the idea if you used predefined alternatives for a `textarea` element.

There is nothing illogical with the idea of a pre-made list of alternatives to use for text area input, but there is nothing for it in HTML at present (or being planned, as far as I known). It can be coded rather simply in JavaScript, though.

You can have a list of items, for example as a `ul` list, or even as a `select` element. You would then add a little JavaScript that causes the item text to be written or appended to the `textarea` element e.g. when an item is clicked on or a selection is made from a `select` list

There is normally no reason to have a single-line text input field as a `textarea`. It’s possible, just not useful, except perhaps in very special cases. Note that `<textarea rows=1 ...>` lets the user enter any number of lines, it just makes that very inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use autocomplete for that case

```
 $('textarea').autocomplete({
      source: Object.values(<your list here>),
  });
```

It look like not good as datalist of input, but it's simple.

Comment: autocomplete requires JQueryUI I believe. Which requires another DNS and download hit. An, a bit of time customizing it.

Answer (score 0):

The `<datalist>` tag is supported in `Internet Explorer 10`, `Firefox`, `Opera`, and `Chrome`.

Note that the `<datalist>` tag is **not** supported in `Internet Explorer 9` and earlier versions, or in `Safari`.

The `<datalist>` tag specifies a list of pre-defined options for an `<input>` element and it is used to **provide an "autocomplete" feature** on `<input>` elements. Users will see a drop-down list of pre-defined options as they input data.

You can use ONLY the `<input>` element's list attribute to bind it together with a `<datalist>` element, not the `<textarea>` element.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) for more details.